# Trouble importing win32com in python 3

Tags: python, windows, import

I'm running 64 bit windows 7 and 64 bit python 3.2. I installed the pywin 32 AMD 64 package and can import win32com in the IDLE, but not in my program. Here's the error  in context:

code:

```
import random
import time
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import webbrowser
import os
import sys
from sys import exit

print('This is was just an add on to the imports...')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from win32com.client import constants
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
 >>>
```

I don't really know what module would be missing, as pywin32 *should* have had everything.
Also, though I do have a previous question regarding win32, I'm re doing everything on a new computer and this in particular is not working. By the way, getting all the packages and modules I have on my desktop to my other computer is becoming quite tedious.

Comment: I tend to prefer the ActiveState install of Python for Windows, it smooths away a lot of the rough edges and bundles up the relevant Windows packages. It may help with your set up tedium as well.

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Installing ActiveState Python instead worked for this. I just hope it doesn't lead to future problems. It seems promising though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer the [ActiveState install of Python for Windows](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads), it smooths away a lot of the rough edges and bundles up the relevant Windows packages. It may help with your set up tedium as well.